# app crash when ever i change the file in assets folder in android

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, android-intent

when i replace my model file the app was crashed with error on these lines. please help me?

**Code:**

```
 public TensorFlowClassifier(final Context context) {
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
    }
```

Error in below line:

```
classifier = new TensorFlowClassifier(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Assets are read-only and cannot be modified. If general, if you ask a question that has "the app crash", please include the full stack trace in the question.

Comment: but i want to replace the file in the assets folder  fraz_model.pb is runnig but ali_har.pb not what can i do sorry i am new in development                                                                                                                               //private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/fraz_model.pb";
     private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/ali_har.pb";

Comment: "i want to replace the file in the assets folder" -- again, that is not possible. Assets are not files on the device, and they cannot be replaced. You would need to save your data to a file. I do not use TensorFlow, so I do not know the details of how you would do that.